# Replace part of word with regexp

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, regex-negation

I need to replace `replaceString` inside words, if it not starting with "@".

For example:

```
replaceString - replaced to : replacedString
abc.replaceString - replaced to : abc.replacedString
abc.@replaceString - NOT replaced
```

Im trying to use something like `@"(?!@)replaceString$"`, but it not working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lookbehind instead of lookahead:

```
(?<!@)replaceString$
```